# viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear called on App Force Quit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, lifecycle

I've got a problem with my applications lifecycle functions viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear. My app works pretty much crashless until I force quit out of it. I did some debugging and the problem seems to be, that when quitting, the methods viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear are called right after I force quit the application.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    print("STARTSCREEN WILL APPEAR")
    
    UserDefaults.standard.set(90, forKey: "user_profile_current_xp")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "user_profile_previous_level_xp")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "user_profile_next_level_xp")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "user_profile_player_level")
    
    updateLevelLabel()
    checkMenuItemLockStatus()
}
```

The app crashes right at the UserDefaults lines because of an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception which makes sense because the app is being erased from memory while for some reason trying to access/set values.

I think the problem wouldn't occur if the viewDidLoad/Appear wouldn't be called on force quitting the app. This just doesn't make any sense to me and I can't remember running into a similar problem with other apps before. Am I missing something, what could trigger those methods when closing the application?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Are you saying that your app crashes the next time it is launched after you force quit it?  I would expect a crash if you force quit the app; You are basically sending a SIGKILL.  Where/how are you seeing the crash?

Comment: "when quitting"  You aren't supposed to do that in iOS.

Comment: @ElTomato You know, people do that - supposed to or not - so you need to consider it. As it's an OS feature to "swipe close" opened apps, it's very well intended by Apple

Comment: @Paulw11 Usually quitting the app does terminate the signal to XCode but not set a breakpoint and a bad access exception before terminating the signal. The crash appears just in XCode, where execution halts and it marks the specific line in red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app stopped crashing when I removed the SceneDelegate from the project. I had to remove it from the Info.plist, edit the AppDelegate (add var window to it) and remove the Scene specific functions from it.

That fixed the crashes for me.